# Does RTCA/DO-254 apply to power electronics?

Tags: aircraft-certification, aircraft-development

DO-254 provides guidance for the development of airborne electronic hardware and it is recognized by the FAA in 2005 via AC 20-152 as a means of compliance for the design of complex electronic hardware.

Is DO-254 only applicable for electronics that perform some kind of 'logic' operations or is it also intended to be used to prove compliance for non-logic electronics, e.g. like power electronics.

Some may argue that power electronics as 'simple' but I believe todays electronic designs have to be considered fairly complex.

Answer (score 4):

The [description of AC 20-152](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/advisory_circulars/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentID/22211) answers your question:

> This advisory circular (AC) applies to manufacturers and installers of ***products or appliances incorporating complex custom micro-coded components with hardware design assurance levels of A, B, and C. These complex custom micro-coded components include application specific integrated circuits (ASIC), programmable logic devices (PLD), field programmable gate arrays (FPGA), or similar electronic components*** used in the design of aircraft systems and equipment. This AC provides a means (but not the only means) to gain Federal Aviation Administration (FAA) approval by showing the equipment design is appropriate for its intended function. Further, using this AC will help you satisfy airworthiness requirements when these types of electronic components are implemented

"Power Electronics" is a term so broad as to be nearly meaningless, but it doesn't matter: If the devices in question are designed to be installed on an airplane; have a DAL of A, B, or C (a failure would be Catastrophic, Hazardous, or Major respectively); and incorporate ASICs, FPGAs, or other circuitry with custom microcode then the FAA's guidance indicates you should comply with DO-254.

---

Note that anything you intend to install on an aircraft needs to demonstrate *to the FAA's satisfaction* that it is not hazardous to safety of flight in both normal and failure conditions, and that it does what you say it does.
Documented compliance with DO-254's guidance is one *acceptable* means of demonstrating the first of those elements (by showing robustness in the design, and graceful failure modes), though it is not the only means. (In other words if you're building a panel-mount cell phone charger or something equally ridiculous nothing indicates that you *must* comply with DO-254, but the FAA may ask you to comply if they feel your device is such that DAL A, B, or C is appropriate.)

Comment: I am not quite sure if this is really the answer to my question, beacuse AC 20-152 addresses only custom micro-coded components. It does not contain any comment regarding non-microcoded components as far as I knoe. For example the means of compliance for 14 CFR Part 25.1301 and 25.1309 can be provided in accordance with AC 20-152 for complex custom micro-coded components.

Comment: @Steffen I've added additional explanation, but with a term so vague as "power electronics" there's not much specific guidance we can give you: That can be anything from a panel-mount cell phone charger to a voltage converter for nav radios -- ***vastly*** different requirements. This is really pretty common sense stuff though: If your device could cause an emergency by failing you're probably going to have to comply with the guidance in DO-254 (or the equivalent) no matter how "simple" or "complex" it is.

Comment: Well, yes. So I also think DO-254 would be usefull to provide verification for compliance to FAR even for "non-logic" devices like power-electronics. Maybe DO-254 is not written for non-logic electronic devices but many artifacts could be adopted. I assume designing a circuit diagram with IGBTs, chokes, capacitors etc. may be interpreted to be the same as coding logic in VHDL.